# Mocked facade with function defined in stdClass undefined

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mockery

Using the following code below I was hoping to bypass the `fit()` function requirement in the code below:

For context, Image is a facade.

Test

```
$image = new stdClass;
$image->fit = function ($x, $y){};

Image::shouldReceive('make')->once()->andReturn(
    $image
);
```

Implementation

```
$image = Image::make($path);
$image->fit(150, 150);
```

Error

```
Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::fit()
```

I have tried making the function `fit()` static

Comment: `fit` isn't a class method. It's a class property containing an anonymous function. See if you can use an [anonymous class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) instead.

Comment: Looks interesting, can't quite get the concept to work locally, do you mind providing an example?

Comment: You can't do that with a methodless class. What you're probably looking for is [Closure::bindTo()](https://www.php.net/closure.bindto)

Comment: @Sherif - Isn't `bindTo()` for assigning scopes to anonymous functions/closures rather than adding them as class methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `$image->fit` is a class property, not a method. You can't call functions inside a property as if it were a method (that would cause issues if you had a property and a method with the same name, for example).

You can try and use an [anonymous class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) instead:

```php
$image = new class() {
    public function fit($x, $y) {
        // some code
    }
};

Image::shouldReceive('make')->once()->andReturn(
    $image
);
```

You just write it as you would a normal class.